# How to make a view fill the width of the parent view and stick to the bottom in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

I'm pulling my hair out and kind of in shock more have not started to riot about how horrible the new autolayout system is from xcode 6 to 7 ....All I want is a simple button to stick to the bottom and fill the width of the view controller on

```
all screen sizes...
 UIButton *bigBottomBtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height-60, self.frame.size.width, 60)];
```

....does not work on all screen sizes for some unknown buggy reason.

Here is what i've tried: 
[image]

....not sure why I can no longer add in constraints the easy way or what the new way even is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Attached screenshot shows how you can do it using Pin Menu (and ignore top spacing example in the picture, I assume you have fixed height for the button)
[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/dFo2xvr nothing man .... nothing:

xcode story: http://imgur.com/dFo2xvr

app:http://imgur.com/hwasBsg

Comment: They ruined xcode and I really have never had a stronger desire to make sure who ever did this to xcode knows how much hell they have put people through by doing a half ass job and not understanding the value of simple.

Comment: Please make sure you are using correct size classes. You attached a screenshot where you installed constraints for wCompact hAny (For iPhone In Portrait) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/SelectingASizeClass.html

Comment: Before this version of xcode it just worked perfect on all sizes by default...anything less is a downgrade, but yes I am viewing on a iphone5s.

Comment: If you want to install constraints for all layouts, select wAny hAny (http://screencast.com/t/IgnFCDR26j) and install constraints for this configuration.

Comment: So what my choices are build a layout in this stretched out screen or and constraints to each and every view x9 times?!? Kind of insane.

Comment: Usually you don't need to build constraints to each view x9 times. But it depends on your app, solutions, designers decisions etc. If the button should be at the bottom and fill the width on all devices and orientations, just select wAny hAny. If you need to have button at the top on iPad, select the same button in wRegular hRegular and install another iPad specific constraint etc.

Comment: PRICELESS.....Is this typical or is there something seriously wrong with my xcode: http://imgur.com/jucANx4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102822/discussion-between-nimble-and-chuckkelly).